# Is there a unified way to store and pass any callable objects?

Tags: c++, function

**Background:**

I have a `Framework` where I work on `Object`s. Up till now I created `Object`s in the framework with a default constructor. Now I want to introduce some customization on creation of the `Object`s. I decided it would be nice to allow to pass a factory into the `Framework`. I call it `Provider`, I will explain why below.

The only thing I expect in the `Framework` is to have a *thing* that will behave something like this

```
template< typename Provider >
void Framework::make_objects( Provider obj_provider)
{
   Object obj = obj_provider();
}
```

I would like `Provider` to be anything that is callable, and returns an `Object` to be passed. E.g:

```
Factory factory;
framework.make_objects( factory.make_object ); // [1] a Factory method
framework.make_objects( []() { return Object(); } ); // [2] lambda 
framework.make_objects( function_that_spits_Object );  // [3] a simple function
```

I call `Provider` a provider, and not a factory, because it is more of just a method of a factory.

**Problem:**

I cannot figure out a way with a simple front-end interface to pass and possibly store any kind of callable object (with a given signature). Is it possible?

**What I tried:**

I tried `std::function`, and got it to work, but gets really ugly when I want to provide `Object`s using a `Factory` method because it is overloaded, and a member method. So I need to bind `factory` instance to an overloaded member method. Possible but really ugly from the user side.

I think a template similar to the one Background example, would work, but it would be extremely nice to be able to store and pass the `Provider`. And I couldn't figure out how the template should be written to allow that.

I know that I can resolve my background/original problem, I could accept a whole `Factory` in the `Framework`, and write a constructor that would accept `std::function` and wrap it, so the function-type providers would implicitly get converted to `Factory`.

However my question for here is, is this possible to implement, to accept and store any kind of callable object, so I can just use `provider()` any where in the framework whenever I need a new object. This is the technical issue I am interested in here.

Comment: `std::function` is created for exactly this purpose. The problem you raise with overloaded member functions is inherent to the fact that member functions need an object to operate on. How do you presume to call a member function otherwise?

Comment: What I believe he wants is for `factory.make_object` to essentially bind itself, which is not a feature offered by C++.

Comment: It's more or less like DeadMG says. I did not really raise a problem with binding, and I understand where it comes from. I was just saying it was ugly and I was asking how can design my code to be more user friendly, because a need to do pretty equilibristic binding was a no-go for me. The proposed workaround with lambda wrap is a really nice alternative. Also I do not really see a problem with automatic binding the call the the object, if I pass it as `factory.make_object`. It is known which instance and which method I want to call, but I might be short-sighted on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just put the member call inside the lambda, e.g. `[factory] { return factory.make_object(); }`. std::function is the solution here.

The problem that binding member functions sucks has nothing to do with what you're going to do with the result- there's no class or type you can use that can solve the problem of producing a wrappable function object in the first place. The syntax of `f(factory.make_object)` is impossible to support for *any type*.

Just use a lambda to wrap the member function and use `std::function`.

Comment: I feel stupid xD. such a nice workaround. I had feeling, just needing the returned object should not bring up such problems, but could not figure out how to write it properly. Just a little note, I needed to declare the lambda mutable, because I want to allow the state of `Factory` to change its state when making `Objects`. I edited the answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: I totally do mind. The details of the lambda in this exact case (e.g. value or ref to the factory) aren't important.